# The number of messages on an MSMQ via Powershell

Tags: powershell, msmq

I'd like to provide a queuepath and get the number of messages thereupon.  Any advice on how this could be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I saw this: [What can I do with C# and Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742262/what-can-i-do-with-c-and-powershell) and went here:http://jopinblog.wordpress.com/2008/03/12/counting-messages-in-an-msmq-messagequeue-from-c/

And made this

```
# Add the .NET assembly MSMQ to the environment.
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging")

# Create a new QueueSizer .NET class help to warp MSMQ calls.
$qsource = @"
public class QueueSizer
    {
        public static System.Messaging.Message PeekWithoutTimeout(System.Messaging.MessageQueue q, System.Messaging.Cursor cursor, System.Messaging.PeekAction action)
        {
            System.Messaging.Message ret = null;
            try
            {
                // Peek at the queue, but timeout in one clock tick.
                ret = q.Peek(new System.TimeSpan(1), cursor, action);
            }
            catch (System.Messaging.MessageQueueException mqe)
            {
                // Trap MSMQ exceptions but only ones relating to timeout. Bubble up any other MSMQ exceptions.
                if (!mqe.Message.ToLower().Contains("timeout"))
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }

        // Main message counting method.
        public static int GetMessageCount(string queuepath)
        {
            // Get a specific MSMQ queue by name.
            System.Messaging.MessageQueue q = new System.Messaging.MessageQueue(queuepath);

            int count = 0;

            // Create a cursor to store the current position in the queue.
            System.Messaging.Cursor cursor = q.CreateCursor();

            // Have quick peak at the queue.
            System.Messaging.Message m = PeekWithoutTimeout(q, cursor, System.Messaging.PeekAction.Current);

            if (m != null)
            {
                count = 1;

                // Keep on iterating through the queue and keep count of the number of messages that are found.
                while ((m = PeekWithoutTimeout(q, cursor, System.Messaging.PeekAction.Next)) != null)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            // Return the tally.
            return count;
        }
    }
"@

# Add the new QueueSizer class helper to the environment.
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $qsource -ReferencedAssemblies C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Messaging\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Messaging.dll

# Call the helper and get the message count.
[QueueSizer]::GetMessageCount('mymachine\private$\myqueue');
```

And it worked.

Comment: +1 good answer.  Also, not sure why, but I had to change "QueueSizer::" to "[QueueSizer]::" in the last line for this script to work.

Comment: @JohnD +1 The square brackets indicate a type. As you mentioned, is required. Because GetMessageCount is a static method, you need to reference the type directly. If it was an instance method you would have to create an object first like $qs = New-Object QueueSizer; then reference $qs.NetMessageCourt...

Comment: this is a terrible answer as it's iterating through the messages and counting them up. Add 1,000,000 messages to your queue and run this and you'll see how long it takes

Answer (score 8):

This will list all queues on a machine and the number of messages:

```
gwmi -class Win32_PerfRawData_MSMQ_MSMQQueue -computerName $computerName |
    ft -prop Name, MessagesInQueue
```

Comment: Actually, I've noticed that the WMI call doesn't always enumerate all the queues.  Not sure why.  I ended up calling [System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::GetPublicQueuesByMachine($machineName) on a list of servers and then used Irwin's [QueueSizer]::GetMessageCount($queuepath) method to get the message count for each queue.

Comment: Is there any way to get more than the first 100 messages out of it?

Comment: Unfortunately, this truncates the queue name to 64 characters as well as only returns the first 97 results. :(

Comment: @RobO is there a way to get a copy of your complete script?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

PowerShell under Windows Server 2012/2012 R2 and Windows 8/8.1 has a bunch built-in Cmdlets that can be used by installing the **Microsoft Message Queue (MSMQ) Server Core** feature.

```
# Get all message queues
Get-MsmqQueue;

# Get all the private message queues.
# Display only the QueueName and MessageCount for each queue.
Get-MsmqQueue -QueueType Private | Format-Table -Property QueueName,MessageCount;
```

There is a number of other Cmdlets that can be used for queue management and message creation. i.e.

- New-MsmqQueue
- Remove-MsmqQueue
- Send-MsmqQueue
- Receive-MsmqQueue
- Get-MsmqQueueManager

For the full list of MSMQ Cmdlet help see [MSMQ Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msmq/), or `Get-Command -Module MSMQ` if you already have the feature installed.

Comment: @RobertMooney That link does not see to work. Yes, there is not a built-in -ComputerName parameter that connects to a remote computer, however you can use PowerShell Remoting.

Comment: Note however that Get-MsMqQueue only works with local queues. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh405018(v=vs.85).aspx.

Answer (score 2):

The solution provided by Irwin is less than idea.

There is a `.GetAllMessages` call you can make to have this done in one check, instead of a foreach loop.

```
$QueueName = "MycomputerName\MyQueueName" 
$QueuesFromDotNet =  new-object System.Messaging.MessageQueue $QueueName


If($QueuesFromDotNet.GetAllMessages().Length -gt $Curr)
{
    //Do Something
}
```

The `.Length` gives you the number of messages in the given queue.

Comment: but is this safe? won't both of these solutions potentially block other processes reading those queue's?

Comment: When you have a queue with tens of thousands of messages, the performance of this method is terrible and is not a good option.

Comment: Same here. This script takes giga bytes of memory for large messages and long queues

Comment: Take a moment and up vote these last two comments (I just did).  Its a fair critique.  For you two, what option worked for you?  Did you up vote that option?  Do you have a better option?  I haven't done MSMQ work in some time and hope to never do it again :-)

Comment: "This is inefficient way to get the message count because it requires to read all messages and store them in array which is in memory. This can cause cause huge memory consumption depending on the frequency, size of the message and current number of messages in the queue and can impact performances of the application."
Better use WMI: https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2018/january/get-number-of-messages-in-msmq-with-c/

Answer (score 2):

following the presciptions from [this link](http://www.meadow.se/wordpress/retrieving-the-message-count-is-msmq-queues/), you can use

```
$queues = Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_msmq_MSMQQueue
$queues | ft -property Name,MessagesInQueue
```

to get the size of the local queues, or

```
$host = ...
$cred = get-credential
$queues = Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_msmq_MSMQQueue -computer $host -credential $cred
$queues | ft -property Name,MessagesInQueue
```

for remote queues.

Comment: this worked perfectly on a old 2008 R2 server with none of the new cmdlets

Answer (score 1):

There are a set of MSMQ management cmdlets in the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com).  Give these a try and see if any of them help (probably Get-MSMQueue):

```
Clear-MSMQueue
Get-MSMQueue
New-MSMQueue
Receive-MSMQueue
Send-MSMQueue
Test-MSMQueue
```

Note: Try grabbing the beta 2.0 module-based distrubtion - just remember to "unblock" the zip before unzipping it.

Comment: PCX requires is installed? I want only XCOPY deploment for execute in remote server

Comment: Later versions of PowerShell ship with the MSMQ module - although I don't know if that module is only available on Win8/Server2012.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for your c# block to get the count.  It uses performance counter to query a single time:

```
public static int GetMessageCount(string machineName, string queuepath)
    {
        var queueCounter = new PerformanceCounter(
            "MSMQ Queue",
            "Messages in Queue",
            string.Format("{0}\\{1}", machineName, queuepath),
            machineName);

        return (int)queueCounter.NextValue();
    }
```

This is more efficient than a repetitive peek, as the work is mostly done on the remote machine, also more efficient than GetAllMessages, as this returns additional message data, then counts the elements - terrible performance at any real load.

Answer (score 1):

I have been hunting high and low for information on accessing queues in a cluster.

For others trying to use powershell commands on clustered queues:

On one of the cluster nodes:

```
$env:computername = "MsmqHostName"
Get-MsmqQueue | Format-Table -Property QueueName,MessageCount
```

remote from the cluster:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$env:computername = "msmqHostName";Get-MsmqQueue | Format-Table -Property QueueName,MessageCount } -ComputerName ClusternNodeName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these...

```
function GetMessageCount2($queuename)
{
    $queuename = $env:computername + "\" + $queuename
    return (Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_msmq_MSMQQueue | Where-Object -filterscript {$_.Name -eq $queuename}).MessagesinQueue 
}

function GetMessageCount3($queuename)
{
    return (Get-MsmqQueue | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.QueueName -eq $queuename}).MessageCount
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a good answer to this, and while Irwin's answer put me on the right basis I was looking for some code that was a bit more Powershell-ish.  The main reason for that is to deal with changes, as you can't `Add-Type` multiple times due to the type being loaded in the .Net runtime, and can't be unloaded without closing your powershell instance.

So I took his answer and came up with:

```
# Add the .NET assembly MSMQ to the environment.
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging") | out-Null

function Get-QueueNames([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$machineName, [String]$servicePrefix)
{
    [System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::GetPrivateQueuesByMachine($machineName) |
        ForEach-Object { $_.Path } | 
        Where-Object { $_ -like "*$($servicePrefix).*" } 
}

function Get-MessageCount([parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$queueName)
{
    function HasMessage
    {
        param
        (
            [System.Messaging.MessageQueue]$queue,
            [System.Messaging.Cursor]$cursor,
            [System.Messaging.PeekAction]$action
        )

        $hasMessage = $false
        try
        {
            $timeout = New-Object System.TimeSpan -ArgumentList 1
            $message = $queue.Peek($timeout, $cursor, $action)
            if ($message -ne $null)
            {
                $hasMessage = $true
            }
        }
        catch [System.Messaging.MessageQueueException]
        {
            # Only trap timeout related exceptions
            if ($_.Exception.Message -notmatch "timeout")
            {
                throw
            }
        }

        $hasMessage
    }

    $count = 0
    $queue = New-Object System.Messaging.MessageQueue -ArgumentList $queueName
    $cursor = $queue.CreateCursor()

    $action = [System.Messaging.PeekAction]::Current
    $hasMessage = HasMessage $queue $cursor $action
    while ($hasMessage)
    {
        $count++
        $action = [System.Messaging.PeekAction]::Next
        $hasMessage = HasMessage $queue $cursor $action
    }

    $count
}

$machineName = "."
$prefix = "something"

Get-QueueNames $machineName $prefix |
    ForEach-Object {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            QueueName = $_
            MessageCount = Get-MessageCount $_
        }
    }
```

It can be optimized so that the first function returns queues instead of the queue names, but I needed both for different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

```
winrm s winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="yourIp"}'
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "YourPassword" -AsPlainText -force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("Domain\Usernama",$securePassword)  
$session = New-PSSession YourIP -credential $credential
$command = {Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_msmq_MSMQQueue | ft -property Name,MessagesinJournalQueue,MessagesInQueue | out-String} 
Invoke-Command -session $session -scriptblock $command
```

[image]

Comment: Some comments would be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging") | Out-Null

$AlertCount = 39

$queuePath = ".\private$\test.pdpvts.error"

$queue = New-Object System.Messaging.MessageQueue $queuePath


If($queue.GetAllMessages().Length -gt $AlertCount)
{
    Send-MailMessage -To "Me" -From "Alerts" -Subject "Message queue is full" -Credential mycridentials -UseSsl -SmtpServer mail.google.com
}
```