# MSMQ command line in win 7

Tags: command-line, msmq

Is there a cmd line for MSMQ basic operation (get the queue size, purge queue).
I tried google it but did not get any think useful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289464/the-number-of-messages-on-an-msmq-via-powershell

Comment: No command line utilities. Also Microsoft's MSMQ PowerShell applet project, sadly, never got off the ground. You'll have to rely on 3rd party solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and the best way is to use powershell, take a look on [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com/)

and you'll be able to invoke following commnads

```
Clear-MSMQueue
Get-MSMQueue
New-MSMQueue
Receive-MSMQueue
Send-MSMQueue
Test-MSMQueue
```

See [**how to purge from cmd**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793441/purge-msmq-queue-and-reset-iis-from-a-bat-file)