# Purge MSMQ queue and reset IIS from a bat file

Tags: batch-file, msmq

Is it possible to purge a msmq queue from a bat file?

Essentially I want to make a bat file or at least something quick and easy so that an untrained employee can click and fix without knowing any shell or admin tools

Could someone please help me in the right direction?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look on [MSMQAdm Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885786.aspx)

Tasks administered through the utility programs include the following:

- Browsing local queues
- **Purging messages**
- Deleting individual messages
- Stopping and starting MSMQ service
- Connecting and disconnecting from the network

Don't forget about powershell, take a look on [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com/)

**Update**

Open powershell and write line by line

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging")
$queueName = '.\Private$\testQueue'
$queue = new-object -TypeName System.Messaging.MessageQueue -ArgumentList $queueName
$queue.Purge()
```

Call powershell from cmd

1. Create txt file.
2. Insert all lines
3. Change file extension on "ps1"

The easiest way call script from cmd.

> powershell.exe -executionpolicy Unrestricted C:\purgemsmq.ps1

Comment: Okay, I will take a look. But essentially I want to make a bat file or at least something quick and easy so that an untrained employee can click and fix without knowing any shell or admin tools.

Comment: Msmq have no command line utilities. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018826/msmq-command-line-in-win-7

Comment: added powershell commands, just open powershell and insert all line by line

Comment: Thank you! Can this in any way be automated?

Comment: Lets do it. 1) Create txt file. 2) Insert all lines 3) Change file extension on "ps1". 4) The easiest way call script from cmd. powershell.exe -executionpolicy Unrestricted C:\purgemsmq.ps1

Answer (score 4):

THis Code Works:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging") | Out-Null 
$Name=(get-wmiobject win32_computersystem).name
$QName=(
"FormatName:Direct=OS:$name\System$;DEADXACT",
"FormatName:Direct=OS:$name\System$;DEADLETTER"
)

foreach ($Q in $Qname){
$MessageQueue = New-Object System.Messaging.MessageQueue($Q)
$MSGCount=$($MessageQueue.GetMessageEnumerator2()).count

IF($MSGCount){
$MessageQueue.Purge()
Write-Host "$Q has been purged of $MSGCount messages." -ForegroundColor green
}
Else{
Write-Host "$Q is clean"}

}
```

Comment: Along with code please try to explain about that as well.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell script to purge all private queues on local machine:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging")
$MachineName=(get-wmiobject win32_computersystem).name
[System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::GetPrivateQueuesByMachine("$MachineName") | % { $_.Purge(); }
```

As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11793579/1235394, easiest way to execute it is:

- save script to file `purge-private-msmq-queues.ps1`
- in the same folder create script file `purge-private-msmq-queues.cmd` with following content:

  ```
  powershell -executionpolicy Unrestricted .\purge-private-msmq-queues.ps1
  ```