# Purge a public MSMQ queue in Powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, msmq

I found this post
[Purge MSMQ queue and reset IIS from a bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793441/purge-msmq-queue-and-reset-iis-from-a-bat-file)

to purge a private MSMQ queue. I thought I could adapt it to purge a public queue by changing `Private` by `Public` but it failed.

How can I purge a public MSMQ queue in Powershell 2.0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it, I had to remove `private$` instead of changing it.

So this does the job :

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging")
$queueName = '.\testQueue'
$queue = new-object -TypeName System.Messaging.MessageQueue -ArgumentList $queueName
$queue.Purge()
```