# Monitor MSMQ time of arrival

Tags: powershell, msmq

I'm trying to put together a script to monitor the MSMQ on a server. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289464/the-number-of-messages-on-an-msmq-via-powershell) and it works like a charm but I also need to get the time of arrival.

When using the Get-Member cmdlet I get a list of properties but none of the seem to get me what I need.

Does anyone know how to get time of arrival?

/G

Comment: As I do not know yet how the messages themselves are processed, this is just a shot into the dark. Would it be a possible solution to just write a log entry in code on arrival?

Comment: I don't think that should be necessary because if you examine the queue you can see the time of arrival, so it is stored somewhere. The question is where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

```
[String]$cName = $Env:COMPUTERNAME
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging") | out-null
[System.Messaging.MessageQueue[]]$queues = [System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::GetPrivateQueuesByMachine($cName.ToLower())
Foreach ($queue in $queues) {
    $queue.MessageReadPropertyFilter.SetAll()
    try {
        [System.Messaging.Message]$message = $queue.Peek(10)
        Write-Host $queue.QueueName $message.ArrivedTime
    }
    catch {
        #Write-Host "Timeout"
    }
}
```

The trick is to set the MessageReadPropertyFilter. It is possible to set each property separately but this will do for now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$qname = "<YourQueueNameHere>"

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging") | out-null

$q = new-object System.Messaging.MessageQueue($qname)

$msgs = $q.GetAllMessages()

foreach ( $msg in $msgs )
{
    Write-Host $msg.ArrivedTime
}
```

Documentation for `Message` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.message%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
Documentation for `Message.ArrivedTime` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.messaging.message.arrivedtime%28v=vs.80%29).

Comment: the output is empty in Windows server 2012

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me. In my case, the script counts how many messages have been received for the past hour.

```
$QueueArray = "MyQueue1.ERRORS", "MyQueue2.ERRORS";

foreach ($queue in $QueueArray)
{
    # Create each MSMQ object
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging") | Out-Null
    $MessageQueue = New-Object System.Messaging.MessageQueue (".\private$\" + $queue)
    
    # Get the amount of the messages in the queue for the past hour.

    $MessageQueue.MessageReadPropertyFilter.SetAll()
    $PastHour = (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)
    $countFailedMessages = 0
    foreach ($message in $MessageQueue )
    {
        if ($PastHour -lt $message.ArrivedTime)
        {
            #Write-Host $message.ArrivedTime
            $countFailedMessages++
            #Write-Host $countFailedMessages
        }
    }
    Write-Host $queue `t $countFailedMessages "failed messages for the past hour"
}
```