# Access Remote MSMQ Count

Tags: c#, msmq

My machine is in Domain D1 and there are public MSMQs in a remote server in domain D2. I am connected through vpn to D2, i.e I can RDP the machine in D2 and access the MSMQ.

What I want is to access (Know the message count) of the MSMQ without RDPing the system. So I build an application for this. I used Impersonation to impersonate the user of D2(i.e used credentials of D2)but the problem is I am not able to access the "Public" MSMQ ( used Messagequeue.GetPublicQueue() ) and exceptions are thrown with message "A workgroup installation computer does not support the operation." but when I used MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueue() it returned a collection of private queue.

I tried using MSMQManager for messageCount
`Path = @"Direct:OS:machine\publicqueue";
FormatName=null;
new MSMQManager.inIt(machineName, path , FormatName);`

This also throws an exception either the queue is not present or not open. but I can check that queue is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you comfortable doing a tiny bit of programming? If not, are you comfortable using PowerShell?

Either way - I would check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289464/the-number-of-messages-on-an-msmq-via-powershell) as it seems to contain the answers you are looking for.

Good luck, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

- Your problem might be that you are working **remotely**.

The method `GetPublicQueuesByMachine()` is indeed **not** available over remote access.

You can see this in a feature matrix in the MSDN documentation: [MessageQueue.GetPublicQueuesByMachine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.getpublicqueuesbymachine.aspx):

> The following table shows whether this method is available in various Workgroup modes.
>
> ```
>  Workgroup mode                         Available
>  --------------                         ---------
>  Local computer                         No
>  Local computer and direct format name  No
>  Remote computer                        No
>  Remote computer and direct format name No
> ```

- Also check the access privileges of your queues.

If I am wrong in the previous suggestion, it might be as simple as experimenting with the access rights for specific users in the network.

MSDN article [Public and private queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776346%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) states:

> Default security access for public queues gives everyone permission to
> send messages to a public queue. **Specific permissions must be
> granted for read access.**

- As for the actual message counting, John Opincar wrote a nice article about counting messages here: [Counting Messages in an MSMQ MessageQueue from C#](http://jopinblog.wordpress.com/2008/03/12/counting-messages-in-an-msmq-messagequeue-from-c/)