# Powershell/Xaml GUI - Variables, Controls, Dynamic Scripts, etc

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, xaml, user-interface

I've stumbled across the lovely concept of integrating xaml, powershell, and cscript files into 'a pretty capable of doing anything on windows' type of program. I never really got into c# even though I did do a little .net in college 15 years ago...

My recent discovery has made me want to learn more about it, and yet, as I started designing some GUI's using the same methods I have, in the past, used to code HTML tables, and eventually CSS Flex/Grid with (pretty much the same idea)... I couldn't help but wonder if there was a way to do this much more quickly and efficiently.

As I was learning how to integrate PS/XAML, I was curious about the possibility of even needing the Xaml file to begin with. Like, what if I could make a list of variables that have nested variables that are called on via an answer file or template, without needing to call in the Xaml file at all?

Perhaps this is pointless, perhaps the xaml is needed in every scenario, which is fine... but can I code the xml with variables that the ps script defines? And is a cscript file even necessary to do all of this?

No PS/XAML code attached. Just a hypothetical at this point... but i'll provide an example of the batch file idea I had which illustrates the point I'm looking to achieve here...

I'm not entirely sure this would work? But it seems like a cool idea to reduce the amount of time necessary to 'do stuff'

```
set "a1=GOOD"
set "h1=ECHO # _______________________________________________________ #"
set "h2=ECHO #                                                         #"
set "h3=ECHO # **********                                   ********** #"
set "h4=ECHO # ******************************************************* #"
set "h5=ECHO #                        %a1%                             #"
set a0="%h4%^%h4%^%h3%^%h3%^%h2%^%h5%^%h2%^%h3%^%h3%^%h4%^%h4%"
set a1=GOOD
%a0%
set a1=BEANS
%a0%
```

---

I'll show examples of what I'm looking to do soon.

Basically, I want to make variables in the Xaml so that I could tell powershell....

```
$gridrow = 3
$gridcol = 4
$currentgrid = $gridrow (3) * $gridcol (4) = (12)
$cg1 = horizontalignment="center", etc content="section 1"
$cg2 = etc etc so forth
```

then it'd have a whole Xaml file that I could replicate and edit far more easily...

obviously it can be done with other methods, but if it can be done without actually saving to a xaml file then that'd be sick.

Answer (score 0):

You create PowerShell GUI using either Windows Forms or WPF. What you posted is a batch file. You can still create console GUI using PowerShell if that is what you are after.

Example Console app:
[Friday Fun – A PowerShell Console Menu](https://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/scripting/1938/friday-fun-a-powershell-console-menu/)
Author's example:

```
#Requires -version 2.0

<#
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Script: Demo-ConsoleMenu.ps1
 Version: 1.0
 Author: Jeffery Hicks
    http://jdhitsolutions.com/blog
    http://twitter.com/JeffHicks
    http://www.ScriptingGeek.com
 Date: 12/30/2011
 Keywords: Read-Host, Menu, Switch
 Comments:
 The best way to create a menu is to use a here string

 Use -ClearScreen if you want to run CLS before displaying the menu

 "Those who forget to script are doomed to repeat their work."

  ****************************************************************
  * DO NOT USE IN A PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT UNTIL YOU HAVE TESTED *
  * THOROUGHLY IN A LAB ENVIRONMENT. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.  IF   *
  * YOU DO NOT UNDERSTAND WHAT THIS SCRIPT DOES OR HOW IT WORKS, *
  * DO NOT USE IT OUTSIDE OF A SECURE, TEST SETTING.             *
  ****************************************************************
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 #>

Function Show-Menu {

Param(
[Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="Enter your menu text")]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[string]$Menu,
[Parameter(Position=1)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[string]$Title="Menu",
[switch]$ClearScreen
)

if ($ClearScreen) {Clear-Host}

#build the menu prompt
$menuPrompt=$title
#add a return
$menuprompt+="`n"
#add an underline
$menuprompt+="-"*$title.Length
$menuprompt+="`n"
#add the menu
$menuPrompt+=$menu

Read-Host -Prompt $menuprompt

} #end function

#define a menu here string
$menu=@"
1 Show info about a computer
2 Show info about someones mailbox
3 Restarts the print spooler
Q Quit

Select a task by number or Q to quit
"@

#Keep looping and running the menu until the user selects Q (or q).
Do {
    #use a Switch construct to take action depending on what menu choice
    #is selected.
    Switch (Show-Menu $menu "My Help Desk Tasks" -clear) {
     "1" {Write-Host "run get info code" -ForegroundColor Yellow
         sleep -seconds 2
         } 
     "2" {Write-Host "run show mailbox code" -ForegroundColor Green
          sleep -seconds 5
          }
     "3" {Write-Host "restart spooler" -ForegroundColor Magenta
         sleep -seconds 2
         }
     "Q" {Write-Host "Goodbye" -ForegroundColor Cyan
         Return
         }
     Default {Write-Warning "Invalid Choice. Try again."
              sleep -milliseconds 750}
    } #switch
} While ($True)
```

Another console example here:

[Creating Menus in Powershell](http://asaconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/08/creating-menus-in-powershell.html)

Otherwise there are plenty of examples of WinForms and WPF GUI development as well all over the web,

Example:
[PowerShell and WPF: Introduction and Building Your First Window](https://learn-powershell.net/2012/09/13/powershell-and-wpf-introduction-and-building-your-first-window/)

YouTube videos if you are more of a visual learner:

[powershell wpf gui](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell%20wpf%20gui)

***Update for the OP on the question***

Understood. 
As for …

> "Basically, I want to make variables in the Xaml so that I could tell
>   powershell.... $gridrow = 3 ...",

So, more details / examples of what you are after is paramount. Yet, you can define variable in XAML and that is documented in MS documents and Q & A posts.

[How can I define a variable in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877304/how-can-i-define-a-variable-in-xaml)

[Can I declare variable in the XAML code?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/4a31652e-8eae-4ddc-9ca4-5e5cafff65fc/can-i-declare-variable-in-the-xaml-code)

> Per the article

```
# After definitition:

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1_delete_test.Window1"  
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"  
    Title="Window1">   
    <Window.Resources>  
        <System:String x:Key="myStr">init</System:String>  
    </Window.Resources>  
    <TextBlock Name="txtBlock" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource myStr}}"/>   
</Window>  

# you can use from code like that:

public partial class Window1 : Window   
    {   
        public Window1()   
        {   
            InitializeComponent();   

            Resources["myStr"] = "string";   

            txtBlock.Text = FindResource("myStr").ToString();   
        }   
    }
```

Comment: I updated the top to more accurately reflect the principle I'm after. I'm not trying to make a powershell console or batch script. I'm trying to eliminate a lot of repetitive code in the xaml file or the xaml file entirely.

Comment: This looks like a good idea or method that could result in an implementation I'm looking to do.  I try to stay away from the C# programming altogether but I'm starting to see that it might not be possible?

I don't really understand C# yet, maybe I just need some kind of primer on how Powershell is different?

Comment: Yeppers, in the long run to really do stuff, PowerShell is a gateway drug to C#. PowerShell and C# are two different things, so, trying to an apples to apples comparison is not really an effort to travel. It's best to know what you can do in PowerShell directly, and when you need to Add C# stuff, and vice versa. You can add C# code to PowerShell scripts using - Add-Type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-6

Comment: See also: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2010/05/07/using-csharp-c-code-in-powershell-scripts/ … and  … https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742262/what-can-i-do-with-c-sharp-and-powershell

Comment: wow, this is pretty useful.

c# and c++ are a whole other story afaic, that's gonna take a bit more time for me to understand. when it comes to batch and powershell, I can get a lot done because I understand the concept of dynamic variables... 

when it comes to c#, i tend to fall apart. same with javascript... but. perhaps I can eventually do what i'm trying to do once I get this GUI i'm working on complete.

I was looking for a way to shorten the overall structure of the work I'm trying to do, but I think copy+paste will do for now lol

Comment: I started looking into c#, I'm trying to learn how to use custom class and constructors in order to control the GUI elements. What is the purpose of declaring a class as public/private or void?